# Returning Self to avoid moving out of borrowing content

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to implement the Monkey toy language in Rust. I'm now trying to generate and AST, but before that, I need to have a functioning parser. I already have my lexer.

So the relevant part of my parser looks like this:

```
struct Parser<'a> {
    lexer: lexer::Lexer<'a>,
    current_token: Token<'a>,
    peek_token: Token<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Parser<'a> {
    // Create a new parser.
    // Depends on a lexer capable of iterating over
    // the tokens.
    pub fn new(mut lexer: lexer::Lexer<'a>) -> Parser {
        // constructor
    }

    // Read the next token.
    //
    // Returns self to avoid weird `move out of
    // borrowed content` issue?
    fn next_token(mut self) -> Self {
        self.current_token = self.peek_token;
        self.peek_token = self.lexer.next_token();
        self
    }
}
```

The problem is in the `next_token` function. I would really like it to work with a borrowed `&self`, like this:

```
// Read the next token.
fn next_token(&mut self) {
    self.current_token = self.peek_token;
    self.peek_token = self.lexer.next_token();
}
```

But the compiler complaints about moving out of a borrowed content. Now, I understand *why* this is happening: I'm only borrowing `self`, I cannot perform the move from `self.peek_token` to `self.current_token` because I do not own it.

My question though, is, is returning `Self` the best strategy? The code which returns `Self` works fine, but the interface just got very very ugly.

```
#[test]
fn test_next_token() {
    let l = lexer::Lexer::new("let answer = 42;");
    let p = Parser::new(l);
    assert_eq!(p.current_token, Token::Let);
    let p = p.next_token();
    assert_eq!(p.current_token, Token::Ident("answer"));
}
```

Is there an alternative I'm not seeing? Is this a common idiom in Rust?

Here is a link to the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=664d4bd68c6fabe447f06e044cbb30ef).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html):

```
use std::mem;

// Read the next token.
fn next_token(&mut self) {
    self.current_token = mem::replace(&mut self.peek_token, self.lexer.next_token());
}
```

`replace` will store the second argument into the first, and return the current value of the first, which we then assign to `current_token`.

Comment: Nice! That worked. Seeing your answer though I do not think I understood so clearly why I couldn't just move out of the variable before? I rechecked the borrowing rules and there's nothing saying that you cannot move out of borrowed content? 

Obviously in my original code rust would invalidate `self.peek_token` after the move, as it could lead to a user after free, right? But why doesn't it just do that instead of saying I can't do it?

Only reason I came up with is that there may be another thread expecting `self.peek_token` to be valid?

Comment: Simply put, because `panic!`. You move out of `peek_token`, invalidating it and expecting to make it valid again with the result of `next_token()`. But if `next_token()` instead panics, and some outer code catches that panic, you have a view of the struct with an invalidated field. (Threading, by the way, is not a concern, because a `&mut` is exclusive and guarantees that no other thread is currently accessing the struct.) By using `replace`, you guarantee that no panics can occur between invalidation and reinitialization.